# Configuring Kafka Appenders with Log4j2 json configuration

Tags: json, apache-kafka, log4j2

I am using log4j2 with a JSON properties file I am naming log4j2.json and attempting to add a kafka appender. There are plenty of examples using the older formats or xml, but struggling to get the correct format in JSON. This is most likely a silly question, but I have been struggling to get this to work and can find no examples anywhere. I am tempted to abandoned configuring log4j2 in json and moving to XML, but I feel this should be rather simple.

Here is a sample kafka appender defined in XML.

```
'<Appenders>
    <Kafka name="Kafka" topic="devglan-test">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%date %message"/>
        <Property name="bootstrap.servers">localhost:9092</Property>
    </Kafka>
    <Async name="Async">
        <AppenderRef ref="Kafka"/>
    </Async>
</Appenders>
```

How does the
     'localhost:9092
entry map to JSON.

I have tried a number of styles such as the following:
'"Kafka": {
                "name":"Kafka",
                "topic":"FEEDPROCESSING_Dev",
                "PatternLayout": {
                    "pattern": "%date %message"
                },
        "bootstrap.servers": [{"name":"localhost:9092"}]}
}

That did not work. I also tried..

```
'"Kafka": {
            "name":"Kafka",
            "topic":"FEEDPROCESSING_SYNC_Dev",
            "PatternLayout": {
                "pattern": "%date %message"
            },
    "Property": {"bootstrap.servers":"localhost:9092"}}
}
```

I am getting errors like: 
Property contains an invalid element or attribute "bootstrap.servers"

THis configuration gives me the error "Unable to locate plugin type for bootstrap.servers":

```
'"Property": {"bootstrap.servers":[{"name":"localhost:9092"}]}}},
```

I know I have the correct maven dependencies..

What is the correct way to configure a Kafka appender, particular the bootstrap server property,using JSON and log4j2?

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct format I think:

```
"Kafka": {
    "name": "Kafka",
    "topic": "FEEDPROCESSING_Dev",
    "PatternLayout": {
        "pattern": "%date %message"
    },
    "Property": {
        "name": "bootstrap.servers",
        "value": "localhost:9092"
    }
}
```